# How to show interstitial ads after 5 button clicks ? (shared preference)

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I was trying to show the interstitial ads after 5 button clicks, below is my code which is not working, kindly someone show me how to solve this. I have tried 2 ways, both are not working.

PS: I'm new to android development.

First Code

```js
int counter = 0;

...



  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

  Button play_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_video);
  play_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
   @Override
      
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter == 5) {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
      counter = 0;
     } else {
      counter++;
      stream(vidData);
      getDialog().dismiss();

     }

     if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

Second Code (Shared Preferance)

```js
private int counter = 0;

.....

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

  Button play_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_video);
  play_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   Context context = getActivity();
   SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

   int counter = preferences.getInt("CounterR", 0);

   @Override

   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() & counter >= 5) {

     counter = 0;
     mInterstitialAd.show();

    } else {

     counter++;

     stream(vidData);
     getDialog().dismiss();

    }
    editor.putInt("CounteR", counter);
    editor.commit();


    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
   }
  });
```

Updated Full Code

```js
private int counter = 0;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vid_alert, container, false);

  close_dialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);

  mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());

  mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

  // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
  mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

  // Create and set AdListener for interstitial
  mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

   public void onAdClosed() {
    // When user closes ad end this activity (go back to first
    // activity)
    finish();
   }

   private void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });

  getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
  final String vidData = mArgs.getString("vid_data");
  final String vidID = mArgs.getString("vid_id");

  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

  Context context = getActivity();
  SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

  Button stream_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stream_video);
  stream_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter == 5) {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
      counter = 0;
     } else {
      // means interstitial not yet loaded,so make a load
      // request
      AdRequest newadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(newadRequest);
      // as nothing will happen when we get inside this else
      // statement, you should call the stream method from
      // here too

      streamFB(vidData);
      getDialog().dismiss();

     }
    } else {
     counter++;
     streamFB(vidData);
     getDialog().dismiss();
    }
   }
  });
  Button close_dialog = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);
  close_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter == 5) {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
      counter = 0;
     } else {
      // means interstitial not yet loaded,so make a load
      // request
      AdRequest newadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(newadRequest);
      // as nothing will happen when we get inside this else
      // statement, you should call the stream method from
      // here too
      getDialog().dismiss();
     }
    } else {
     counter++;
     getDialog().dismiss();
    }
   }
  });
  // Do something else
  return rootView;
```

Comment: Read Dangling else problem.

Comment: Hi thanks, Please check the updated full code, I have followed Ravinder's instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with your logic, the else part should come with the outer if, check my code below:

```
if (counter == 5) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                counter = 0;
            }else{
                // means interstitial not yet loaded,so make a load request
                AdRequest newadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(newadRequest);
                // as nothing will happen when we get inside this else statement, you should call the stream method from here too
                stream(vidData);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        }else {
            counter++;
            stream(vidData);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
```

move this code in your onclick method. let me know if it worked, edited directly here on stackoverflow, please check the syntax errors too, there might be one or two.

Comment: Hi, Ravinder , first of all, thanks for helping me, but the code you have provided is not working, which means the interstitial ad is not showing with the button click. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Add a log inside If(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) block and check if it gets printed in logcat. If yes then there must be something wrong with the way you have initialised admob ads, also check you have enabled test ads on google admob dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Remove counter = 0 after mInterstitialAd.show(); from the if condition and place it in the onAdClosed() function see example below:
`mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                counter=0;
                startNewGame();
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it is not working than most probably there is problem in your ads code.

```
int counter = 0;

        ...



                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                Button play_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_video);
                play_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (counter != 5) {
                            counter++;
                            stream(vidData);
                            getDialog().dismiss();
                           }
                        else if (counter ==5){
                            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitialAd.show();
                                counter = 0;
                            } 
                            }

                            if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: still the ads are not loading, I have updated my full code, have you checked it?